# Use socket.io in routes file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Im trying to pass socket and use them in routes files .

I'm exporting my **routes.js** module

```
module.exports = function (client) {

  var express = require("express"); // call express
  var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
  var admin = require("firebase-admin");

  router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    client.on('save-message', function (socket) { console.log("heheyy") })
  });
  router
    .route("/")
    .get(function (req, res, err) {

       ... route stuff...
      });
  router
    .route("/")
    .post(function (req, res, err) {
       ... route stuff
    });
}
//module.exports = router; **commented**
```

in my **server.js** I include routes module then I use it in socket connection function

```
var http = require("http");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = process.env.app_port || 8080; // set our port
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var routerProj = require("./routes/routes");

var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,*");
  next();
});
var config = {
  .... configuration
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


var serviceAccount = require("./ServiceAcountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://datatable-18f93.firebaseio.com"
});
app.use("/v1", routerProj, function (req) {
  //Create HTTP server and listen on port 8000 for requests


});
// Print URL for accessing server
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
io.on("connection", function (client) {
  console.log("Un client est connecté !");
   routerProj(client);
});
```

When I wrap my routes file in a module-function the routes does not work and dont fetch or insert data. so sockets also does not work.

for information sockets work in the **server.js** file

Comment: There are dozens of duplicates of this question here on stack overflow.

Comment: It's not really the same thing every time. I have read many but not get a solution