# How to use socket.io across diffrent routes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have different routes in my `node js` application and i have to use `socket.io` in **every route** to make my `node` and `react js` application realtime. But, i have the below structure of my **node js** application.

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const worksheetController = require('../controllers/worksheet')
const attendenceController = require('../controllers/attendence')

router.route('/worksheets')
 .get(
    worksheetController.getWorksheet
 )
 .post(
    worksheetController.validateWorksheet,
    worksheetController.addWorksheet,
    attendenceController.markAttendence
 )  

router.route('/attendances')
 .get(
    attendenceController.getAttendance
 )

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('./router');

const app = express();
app.use('/api', router);

app.listen('5000', () => {
  console.log('Listening on port');
});

module.exports = app;
```

> So, I want to know
>
> 1) Should i need to use `http` module to create a server, if i need to use socket.io.
>
> 2) How can i use socket.io for diffrent routes.

I found posts that match's to my question on stackoverflow, which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856190/use-socket-io-inside-a-express-routes-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870304/using-socket-io-in-routes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040491/use-socket-io-in-routes-file). But i don't think, that works for me. So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `http` module or other module in document of socket.io for to use `socket.io`
2. I don't sure your idea. But when you want implement socket.io. I think you should run another node app. (Meaning you have 2 nodejs app. 1 for node http normally and 1 for socket.io app). After you can use `path` option when init socket.io app `https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#new-Server-httpServer-options`. Because when you deploy to production. You should run your socket.io app with beside of proxy serve (ex: nginx). Socket.io basically support multi transport and protocol. So if use with http restful. How about config your connection mapping from nginx to socket.io app, how you setup error handler ?.

In your case:
+ Create new file socket.js:

```
// socket.js
var http = require('http')
var socket_io = require('socket.io')

function init_socket(app) {
    const server = http.Server(app)
    const io = socket_io(server, { path: 'your-path-want-for-socket-io' }) // default: /socket.io/
}
```

```js
import {init_socket} from 'socket.js'
init_socket(app)
```